# I am getting a weird error when using discord voice on firefox. Should I be worried?

Tags: firefox, windows-11, xml, discord

I am getting a weird error when using discord voice on Firefox.

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: chrome://browser/content/webrtcIndicator.xhtml
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

[image: screen shot of error]

Should I be worried?

Comment: This also started happening to me recently, but the bug has been [known for 3 years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1639821).

Comment: Same here, it happens when I join a google meet from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Firefox bug, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1639821

Although marked as fixed I also experienced it with the latest version.